# Template argument and its own template argument both contain identically-named types; how can I reference the second in a function signature?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, compiler-bug

Consider this code:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    typedef T t_type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    typedef T t_type; 
};

template<typename U>
auto f() -> typename U::t_type::t_type
{
    return typename U::t_type::t_type();
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    typedef Foo<Bar<int>> Baz;
    f<Baz>();
}
```

It doesn't compile under VS2012:

> invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'U::t_type::{ctor} f(void)'

Seemingly, the compiler is concluding that the second `t_type` in `typename U::t_type::t_type` is naming a constructor rather than an identically-named nested type. Is there anything I can do to help clarify the situation?

Comment: The code compiles in both g++ and clang. Might this be a VC bug?

Comment: The code does compile with g++ (4.8.2) and clang (3.4)

Comment: As a workaround, consider adding a layer of indirection. `template <class T> struct get_t_type { typedef typename T::t_type type; };`, and then the return type becomes `typename get_t_type<typename get_t_type<U>::type>::type`. (VS2012 doesn't have alias templates, or this would have been easier.)

Comment: VS2013.3 gives the same error - consider filing an issue on http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: BTW, `main` function seems to be ill formed. The second parameter should be `char **`.

Comment: It also compiles with EDG. A constructor is not an acceptable lookup result in that context, so it should find the nested type instead ([class.qual]/2) and so it's a VC++ bug.

Comment: @borisbn You're right; fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you're missing a `typename` keyword

```
template<typename U>
auto f() -> typename U::t_type::t_type
{
    return typename U::t_type::t_type();
}
```

and main should have arguments `(int,char**)`.

That said..

this [has already been reported and apparently fixed](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/932109/c2770-emitted-when-trying-to-use-a-nested-typedef-in-a-template-function) (*[will be/has been]* shipped in an unspecified "*future version*"). MSVC 2013 update 4 is also affected.

The proposed workaround is:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    typedef T t_type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    typedef T t_type;
};

template<typename U>
auto f() -> typename U::t_type::template t_type
                                ^^^^^^^^
{
    return typename U::t_type::t_type();
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    typedef Foo<Bar<int>> Baz;
    f<Baz>();
}
```

although if you use the code above everything proceeds as in the following image:

[image]

Comment: You must have started typing almost as soon as I submitted the question, because I noticed and fixed the missing `typename` almost right away :) (the issue with `main`'s signature took longer...). Anyway, this suggestion does work for VS2012.

Comment: @dlf Good to know for VS2012, I don't have a copy off-hand

Comment: So why does the workaround make Clang/gcc unhappy? Is that a bug on their part, or is this use of `template` an MS extension?

Comment: @dlf the bug report I linked explains it

Comment: Oops; I read "incorrect" as "correct." There's something elegantly terrible about using one bug to solve another.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported in 2012, but:

```
template<class T>
using t_type=typename T::t_type;

template<typename U>
t_type<t_type<U>> f() {
  return {};
}
```

For 2012, we could try this:

```
template<class T, size_t recurse>
struct r_type:
  r_type<typename T::t_type, recurse-1>
{};
template<class T>
struct r_type<T, 0> {
  typedef typename T::t_type t_type;
};
```

...

```
template<typename U>
auto f() -> typename r_type<U,1>::t_type {
  return {};
}
```

where `r_type` stands for "recursive type".

Comment: The alias idea occurred to me, but you're correct that it isn't supported in 2012. Your second suggestion does the trick, though.